# Arithmetic operations in the head of a clause

Tags: prolog, logic-programming

I am a writing Prolog predicate that would compare some point (`myPosition(2,2)`) in Cartesian coordinate system with some other point in the neighbourhood. As a result, it should show the direction (north, east, south, west) that we should choose to get from `myPosition(2,2)` to that point. Here is the code of my `.pl` file:

```
myPosition(2,2).

turn_to_east(X+1,Y) :-
    myPosition(X,Y),
    write('East.').

turn_to_west(X-1,Y) :-
    myPosition(X,Y),
    write('West.').

turn_to_north(X,Y+1) :-
    myPosition(X,Y),
    write('North.').

turn_to_south(X,Y-1) :-
    myPosition(X,Y),
    write('South.').

turn_to_the_point(X,Y) :- turn_to_east(X,Y).
turn_to_the_point(X,Y) :- turn_to_west(X,Y).
turn_to_the_point(X,Y) :- turn_to_north(X,Y).
turn_to_the_point(X,Y) :- turn_to_south(X,Y).
```

Then, when I upload the file to SWI-Prolog and write:

```
turn_to_the_point(1,2).
```

I get just:

```
false.
```

Why can't I get the answer 'West.' or any other?

Comment: Prolog isn't like other languages. It doesn't have functions that return values. It has predicates that either succeed, fail, or don't terminate (bad). And it doesn't do *in-line* expression evaluation. So `turn_to_west(X-1,Y)` for example doesn't decrement `X` by 1.

Comment: First of all some terminology: in Prolog, there are no *functions*, these are *predicates*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that by default Prolog does **not interpret `+`, `-`** and other arithmetic operators. `1+1` is simply `1+1` (this is syntactical sugar for `+(1,1)`), **not 2**. This could be useful if you for instance would like to define your own expression evaluator, and you see `+` as the boolean sum, or something completely different.

There is however one way to *collapse* such expression such that it derives `2` out of `1+1` using the [`(is)/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=is/2) predicate. For instance:

```
turn_to_east(NX,Y) :-
    myPosition(X,Y),
    NX is X+1,
    write('East.').
```

Given you query `turn_to_east/2` with `turn_to_east(1,2)`, `NX = 1`. Now you fetch the `myPosition/2` data: `X = 2` and `Y = 2`. Prolog does an equivalence check in the meantime and sees that the Y-coordinate of `turn_to_east/2` is the same as the one of `myPosition`. Next it collapses `2+1` to `3` and sees that this is not equivalent to `NX = 1` so this predicate fails. But if you had queried `turn_to_east(3,1)` it would have succeeded and thus write `East.`.

If you modify your entire theory with the above discussed concept, like:

```
myPosition(2,2).

turn_to_east(NX,Y) :-
    myPosition(X,Y),
    NX is X+1,
    write('East.').

turn_to_west(NX,Y) :-
    myPosition(X,Y),
    NX is X-1,
    write('West.').

turn_to_north(X,NY) :-
    myPosition(X,Y),
    NY is Y+1,
    write('North.').

turn_to_south(X,NY) :-
    myPosition(X,Y),
    NY is Y-1,
    write('South.').

turn_to_the_point(X,Y) :- turn_to_east(X,Y).
turn_to_the_point(X,Y) :- turn_to_west(X,Y).
turn_to_the_point(X,Y) :- turn_to_north(X,Y).
turn_to_the_point(X,Y) :- turn_to_south(X,Y).
```

It answers the query correctly:

```
?- turn_to_the_point(1,2).
West.
true ;
false.
```

A note in general is that predicates better not have side-effects like `write/1` stuff: this is not only for Prolog, almost all programming languages advice to split a program into *calculation* and *interaction*. Perhaps a better way to solve this, is to see the direction as an parameter:

```
myPosition(2,2).

turn_to_point(NX,Y,east) :-
    myPosition(X,Y),
    NX is X+1.
turn_to_point(NX,Y,west) :-
    myPosition(X,Y),
    NX is X-1.

turn_to_point(X,NY,north) :-
    myPosition(X,Y),
    NY is Y+1.

turn_to_point(X,NY,south) :-
    myPosition(X,Y),
    NY is Y-1.

turn_to_the_point(X,Y) :-
    turn_to_point(X,Y,D),
    write(D).
```

In that case the `turn_to_the_point/2` predicate is clearly an interaction predicate whereas its `turn_to_the_point/3` variant does computations.